# Read & evaluate cell as keyword in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have a table called `providers` where the column `notice_period` takes values such as `interval '1 month' - interval '2 days'`. If I do the following:

`select to_date('11.11.2020', 'dd-mm-yyyyy') + notice_period from providers`
I get the following error:

> 42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: ` text

How can I avoid this error and use the value of `notice_period` to directly calculate a valid date?

Cheers

Comment: The error message specifically shows the backtick, but the command you show doesn't contain any backticks.  I think what you show us does not match what you are actually running, due to some quoting or escaping issue.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres readily converts intervals to strings.  I would recommend removing the `interval` key word and just using `::interval`:

```
select date_trunc('year', now()) + notice_period::interval
from (values ('1 day'), ( '3 month 1 day')) v(notice_period)
```

If you insist on the `interval` in the string, then remove it:

```
+ replace(notice_period, 'interval ', '')::interval
```

or:

```
+ substr(notice_period, 10)::interval
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use dynamic SQL in a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION add_period(timestamp with time zone) RETURNS timestamp with time zone
   LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT AS
$$DECLARE
   result timestamp with time zone;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format(
              'SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE %L + %s',
              $1,
              (SELECT notice_period FROM providers)
           ) INTO result;
   RETURN result;
END;$$;
```

The problem with that is that the whole thing is vulnerable to SQL injection by bad values in the table `providers`, so use that only if you can trust the source.

This problem cannot be avoided with SQL strings supplied from outside.